# Cannot write to file when using task manager for python script

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, windows-7-x64

I have created a python script that given an input file, will run NMap on arguments from the input file. It then writes to an output file in csv format. My script works fine and as intended when I run from IDLE, but when my script runs from the task manager, it never overwrites the excel/csv file I tell my script to write to. The path I provide in the file:

```
ipResults = r'C:\Users\________\Documents\Results.csv'
```

I've left out the username for security concerns.

I've set the script to run when I log on. When I log on, I see the output/results in a taskeng.exe window with with a python symbol and rocketship. But when it finishes running, Results.csv does not get updated. As said previously, when running through IDLE, the script does overwrite Results.csv.

Currently I have set my file to both w+ changing it from w to see if that's the error but no such luck. I'm fine with the program overwriting my past results, in fact that's what I want, but when my script is ran through the task manager it does not overwrite the Results.csv file.

Comment: Found similar question here: https://superuser.com/questions/902812/why-doesnt-my-python-script-save-the-file-when-i-use-task-scheduler. Will update if this does or checking the run with highest priveledges box does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply checking the run with highest privilege box when setting the task up on task manager fixed my error, I am now able to write to my output file.